# Llamar a funcion desde archivo externo y deshabilitar input text

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de llamar a una funcion "uncheck()" desde la ruta /js/functions.js pero no logro realizar el llamado.

Tambien ya tengo la funcion para que se seleccione solo 1 checkbox a la vez, Pero necesito que al hacer click en el checkbox 1 tambien se de deshabilite el texto2.

Adjunto el codigo:

```js
function uncheck() {
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("agencia");
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("domicilio");
    checkbox1.onclick = function() {
        if (checkbox1.checked != false) {
            checkbox2.checked = null;

        }
    }
    checkbox2.onclick = function() {
        if (checkbox2.checked != false) {
            checkbox1.checked = null;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script>
    
    <fieldset class="cajas">
            <legend>Modo de envio</legend><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="agencia" onclick="uncheck()" value="Agencia">Agencia<br>
            <label for="agen"></label>
            
            <input class="centrar" name="Agencia" id="agen" placeholder="texto1">
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox" name="Modo" id="domicilio" onclick="uncheck()"      value="Domicilio">Domicilio<br>
            
            <label for="direccion"></label>
            <input class="centrar" name="Direccion" id="Nombre" placeholder="texto2">
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Intentalo de nuevo, abre la consola y checa si obtienes algún mensaje de error

Comment: Revisa que la ruta con la que estas llamando al archivo js sea correcta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una propuesta utilizando el evento `DOMContentLoaded` para que la función se ejecute una vez cargado el **DOM** se deshabiliten ambos ***input***, luego añado un evento a cada *checkbox* para que habilite el *input* asociado y deshabilite el otro *checkbox* (cambie algunos ID para no confundirme), quedaría así:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('agen').disabled = true;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('domi').disabled = true;
    
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('agencia');
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('domicilio');

checkbox1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('agen').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('domicilio').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('agen').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('domicilio').disabled = false;
        }
});

checkbox2.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('domi').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('agencia').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('domi').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('agencia').disabled = false;
        }
});
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script>
 
<fieldset class="cajas">
<legend>Modo de envio</legend><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="modo" id="agencia" value="Agencia">Agencia
<br>
<label for="agen"></label>
<input class="centrar" name="agencia" id="agen" placeholder="texto1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="modo" id="domicilio" value="Domicilio">Domicilio
<br>
<label for="domi"></label>
<input class="centrar" name="domicilio" id="domi" placeholder="texto2">
</fieldset>
```

En cuanto al problema de la llamada al archivo js te recomiendo que revises que la ruta que estás utilizando este correcta.

Comment: muchas gracias x la pronta respuesta